# Preventing apps from posting on my wall on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

On Facebook, whenever a friend of mine does something with a Facebook application he/she uses, a post appears on my wall related to that. I can click on that post and select "Hide xxxxx application" to eliminate future disturbances. Is it possible to disable those annoying posts completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a greasemonkey script for blocking all pending invitations you currently have but there is obviously no way to block all applications in facebook with one click - this would pretty much destroy the whole business model of facebook.

It shouldn't be too stressful to block the apps as they come - I did this for one week and now it happens VERY VERY rarely that I ever see a new app on my wall. There are 5 to 10 annoying apps that are wide spread - once you blocked them it should be very quiet on your wall.

Comment: There actually is a switch to block all the applications.  http://www.labnol.org/internet/block-facebook-applications/14046/

Answer (score 3):

Built in Solution:

> To disable the Facebook apps platform, log in to your Facebook account, select Privacy Settings under Account and then click “Edit your settings” under the Applications and Websites section. Here you’ll see an option to turn off all the platform applications with a single click

[Source](http://www.labnol.org/internet/block-facebook-applications/14046/)